# Jamaica: Permanent residence vs. Unconditional landing

Tags: retirement

"Unconditional Landing" is a stamp placed in a foreign passport that allows the holder to remain in Jamaica, unconditionally.  The fee to apply is JM$10,000 (currently about US$65).  Renewal (new stamp when you get a new passport) has a fee of JM$5,000.

So a US citizen who retires at age 50 and lives to be 120 could pay JM$45,000 to live in Jamaica (or to come and go freely, since this hypothetical guy loves to wander the world).  Are there any gotchas, like not allowed to be out of the country for long?  (Again, this guy likes to travel a **lot**.)

Is there any reason he should instead pay the much higher one-time fee of JM$100,000 for a "Permanent Residence"?

Don't waste words trying to talk me out of going to Jamaica.  I have **no plans** to do so; I'm just researching **all** countries.  (And I'm already aware of the high crime rate.)

Answer (score 0):

US citizen retiring in Jamaica [doesn't qualify](https://www.pica.gov.jm/immigration/unconditional-landing) for "Unconditional Landing" stamp. They may be able to qualify for the permanent residency (retirement is [one of the allowed reasons](https://www.pica.gov.jm/immigration/permanent-residence)).

The eligibility criteria for "Unconditional Landing" as listed on that PICA site are:

- Citizen by birth in Jamaica, who's traveling on their foreign passport
- Naturalized citizen in Jamaica
- Person of Jamaican descent (Jamaican parents or grandparents)
- A national of any of the CARICOM countries.

A US citizen retiree doesn't fit any of these, just by being a US citizen *or* retiree.

For permanent residency, however, retirement is one of the listed available reasons for submitting a request. A US citizen wishing to retire in Jamaica may apply for permanent residency. According to the [Jamaican High Commission in the UK](http://www.jhcuk.org/citizens/citizenship/permanent-residence):

> ... this application must be made in person and can only be done in Jamaica ...

Comment: You cited the same page that I quoted.  Nothing there says persons retiring may not use this.  It _does_ say it allows "attend school or work without having to obtain a student visa or a work permit" but it does not say that nothing else is allowed.  Hence the question.  The page also has no link to any application form, nor where to send/deliver the application.

Comment: @WGroleau you didn't provide any links, the page(s) I cited list eligibility criteria. There's no eligibility criteria that a US citizen retiree would fit for "unconditional landing". There potentially is one for "permanent residence". The "unconditional landing" thing seems to be tailored specifically for people of Jamaican descent or the CARICOM nationals (US is not part of that organization).

Comment: @WGroleau the page does list contact address and location, it's the PICA - the Jamaican immigration agency. On the Jamaican High Commission in the UK webpage they specifically say that application for PR should be done in person in Jamaica.